# Postgres RDS database DB connections increasing infinitely on Saturdays causing "JDBCConnectionException" in Spring Boot Java API app

Tags: java, postgresql, session, amazon-rds, dbconnection

**UPDATE** Added Read/Write Throughput, IOPS, and Queue-Depth graphs metrics and marked graph at time-position where errors I speak of started

**NOTE:** Hi, just looking for suggestions of what could possibly be causing this issue from experienced DBA or database developers (or anyone that would have knowledge for that matter). Some of the logs/data I have are sensitive, so I cannot repost here but I did my best to provide screen shots and data from my debugging so it would allow people to help me. Thank you.

Hello, I have a **Postgres RDS database** (version 12.7 engine) that is hosted on Amazon (AWS). This database is "hit" or called by a API client (Spring Boot/Web/Hibernate/JPA Java API) thousands of times per hour. It is **only executing one 1 hibernate sql query on the backend that is on a Postgres View across 5 tables**. queryDB instance (class = **db.m5.2xlarge**) specs are:

```
8 vCPU
32 GB RAM
Provisioned IOPS SSD Storage Type
800 GiB Storage
15000 Provisioned IOPS
```

The issue I am seeing is on Saturdays I wake up to many logs of **JDBCConnectionExceptions** and I noticed my API Docker containers (Defined as Service-Task on ECS) which are hosted on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) will start **failing** and return a `HTTP 503` error, e.g.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Upon checking AWS RDS DB status, I can see also the sessions/connections increase dramatically, as seen in image below with **~600 connections**. It will keep increasing, seeming to not stop.
[image]

Upon checking the postgres database `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity` tables when I started getting all these JDBCConnectionExceptions and the DB Connections jumped to around ~400 (at this specific time), I did indeed see many of my API queries logged with interesting statuses. I exported the data to CSV and have included an excerpt below:

```
wait_event_type   wait_event         state.                                         query
---------------   ------------       ---------------------------------------------  ----- 
IO                DataFileRead       active (480 times logged in pg_stat_activity)  SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
IO                DataFileRead       idle (13 times logged in pg_stat_activity)     SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
IO                DataFilePreFetch   active (57 times logged in pg_stat_activity)   SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
IO                DataFilePreFetch   idle (2 times logged in pg_stat_activity)      SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
Client            ClientRead         idle (196 times logged in pg_stat_activity)    SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
Client            ClientRead         active (10 times logged in pg_stat_activity)   SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
LWLock            BufferIO           idle (1 times logged in pg_stat_activity)      SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
LWLock            BufferIO           active (7 times logged in pg_stat_activity)    SELECT * ... FROM ... query from API on postgres View
```

If I look at my `pg_stats_activity` table when my API and DB are running and stable, the majority of the rows from the API query are simply `Client ClientRead idle` status, so I feel something is wrong here.

[image]

You can see the below "performance metrics" on the DB at the time this happened (i.e. roughly 19:55 UTC or 2:55PM CST), the DataFileRead and DataFilePrefetch are astronomically high and keep increasing, which backs up the `pg_stat_activity` data I posted above. Also, as I stated above, during normal DB use when it is stable, the API queries will simply be in `Client ClientRead Idle` status in pg_stat_activity table, the the numerous DataFileRead/Prefetches/IO and ExclusiveLocks confuses me.

I don't expect anyone to debug this for me, though I would appreciate it if a DBA or someone who has experienced similiar could narrow down the issue possibly for me. I honestly wasn't sure if it was an API query taking too long (wouldn't make sense, because API has ben running stable for years), something running on the Postgres DB without my knowledge on Saturday (I really think something like this is going on), or a bad postgresql Query coming into the DB that LOCKS UP the resources and causes a deadlock (doesn't completely make sense to me as I read Postgres resolves deadlocks on its own). Also, as I stated before, all the API calls that make an SQL query on the backend are just doing `SELECT ... FROM ...` on a Postgres VIEW, and from what I understand, you can do concurrent SELECTS with ExclusiveLocks so.....

Would take any advice here or suggestions for possible causes of this issue

**Read-Throughput** (first JdbcConnectionException occured around 2:58PM CST or 14:58, so I marked the graph where READ throughput starts to drop since the DB queries are timing out and API containers are failing)
[image]

**Write-Throughput** (API only READS so I'm assuming spikes here are for writing to Replica RDS to keep in-sync)
[image]

**Total IOPS** (IOPS gradually increasing from morning i.e. 8AM, but that is expected as API calls were increasing, but these total counts of API calls match other days when there are 0 issues so doesn't really point to cause of this issue)
[image]

**Queue-Depth** (you can see where I marked graph and where it spikes is exactly around 14:58 or 2:58PM where first JdbcConnectionExceptions start occuring, API queries start timing out, and Db connections start to increase exponentially)
[image]

**EBS IO Balance** (burst balance basically dropped to 0 at this time as-well)
[image]

**Performance Insights** (DataFileRead, DataFilePrefetch, buffer_io, etc)
[image]

Comment: If weird queries were coming in, you would notice their query text in pg_stat_activity, wouldn't you?  Are all the connections from the same IP (of the App server) and as the same user as you expect?

Comment: You have shown us monitoring of the IO wait time, but what about the IO throughput?

Comment: @jjanes yes, all the SELECT queries are from my API and there isn't any weird queries in there . The only "weird thing" is that , when it fails like this, all the wait_types and such are IO/DateFileRead/Fetch, normally , it's never like that - all the queries logged in that pg_stat_table from my API are simply "Client ClientRead Idle",  also, when Db connections increase to 700+, there is an equal amount of ExclusiveLocks (700+) in the pg_lock table. But yes, IPs all match the API docker containers running on AWS ECS cluster. I will post the IO throughput now, thx

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like your app server is getting more and more demanding and the database can't keep up.  Most of the rest of your observations are just a natural consequence of that.  Why it is happening is probably best investigated from the app server, not from the database server.  Either it is making more and more requests, or each one is takes more IO to fulfill.  (You could maybe fix this on the database by making it more efficient, like adding a missing index, but that would require you sharing the query and/or its execution plan).

It looks like your app server is configured to maintain 200 connections at all times, even if almost all of them are idle.  So, that is what it does.

And that is what `ClientRead` wait_event is, it is just sitting there idle trying to read the next request from the client but is not getting any.  There are probably a handful of other connections which are actively receiving and processing requests, doing all the real work but occupying a small fraction of pg_stat_activity.  All of those extra idle connections aren't doing any good.  But they probably aren't doing any real harm either, other than making pg_stat_activity look untidy, and confusing you.

But once the app server starts generating requests faster than they can be serviced, the in-flight requests start piling up, and the app server is configured to keep adding more and more connections.  But you can't bully the disk drives into delivering more throughput just by opening more connections (at least not once you have met a certain threshold where it is fully saturated).  So the more active connections you have, the more they have to divide the same amount of IO between them, and the slower each one gets.  Having these 700 extra connections all waiting isn't going to make the data arrive faster.  Having more connections isn't doing any good, and is probably doing some harm as it creates contention and dealing with contention is itself a resource drain.

The ExclusiveLocks you mention are probably the locks each active session has on its own transaction ID. They wouldn't be a cause of problems, just an indication you have a lot of active sessions.

The BufferIO is what you get when two sessions want the exact same data at the same time.  One asks for the data (DataFileRead) and the other asks to be notified when the first one is done (BufferIO).

Comment: my Hikari configuration is   maximumPoolSize: 30
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      minimum-idle: 10

Comment: Do you have 20 of them running?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to investigate.

Query performance can degrade over time. The amount of data being requested can increase, especially with date predicated ones. Look at Performance Insights you can see how many blocks are read(disk/io), hit(from the buffer) You want as much hit as possible. The loss of burst balance is a real indicator that this is something that is happening. Its not an issue during the week as you have less requests.

The actual amount of shared buffers you have to service these queries, the default is 25% of RAM, you could tweak this to be higher, some say 40%.. Its a dark art and you will unlikely find an answer outside of tweak and test.

Vacuum and analyzing your tables. Data comes from somewhere right? With updates and deletes and inserts tables grow get full of garbage etc. At a certain point the autovacuum processes aren't enough at default levels. You can tweak these to be more agressive, manually fire at night etc.

Index management, same as above.

[Autovacuum docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html)

[Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html)

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you've shared I would guess your connections are not being properly closed.

Comment: How would database being functioning normally almost every week/month, except select Saturdays? That  is perplexing me. Also, I did a total count of API calls coming in on these days where these "mysterious" failures occur and the total # of API calls matches most other days when there are 0 issues.  Could it be a dead-lock issue? doesn't all the IO/DataFileRead processes and equal number ExclusiveLocks (700+) mean that some queries locked up the tables and and thus, the queries timed out, returned 500 server error, then AWS begins creating new containers, causing infinite db connections?

Comment: Also, I am using Spring Boot Hibernate/Data JPA in my API, which comes with Hikari connection pooling, so I believe the Hikari manages closing the Db connections so its not something I need to do